Dynamic tag class in Angular17+
My navbar doesn't react on page change
My app.component.html
<html>
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</html>

This tag starts my navbar.component.html segment
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-center" + {{navType}}>

If it matters here is the idea on the component page
navType: string = "nav-other";
    if (this.router.url === '') { 
      this.navType = "navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-center nav-splash";
    }

The following were tried:
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-center + {{navType}}">
<nav [ngClass]={{navType}}> // With full class exchanged for editing one word
<nav [ngClass]="navType"> // With full class exchanged for editing one word


please share how you are updating navType when the page changes, if possible a working stackblitz with the issue replicated

You need to use Angular's Router to listen for route changes and then update your navType.


ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if (event.url === '' || event.url === '/') {
          this.navType = 'nav-splash';
        } else {
          this.navType = 'nav-other';
        }
      }
    });
  }
<nav class="..." [ngClass]="navType"></nav>



Check this example on stackblitz
